# Remove folder from git but fatal outside repository error while already pushed

Tags: git, repository, rm

I am using AWS Cloud9

I was fiddling around installing/updating nvm in my git repo and then afterwards I git pushed everything to my Github repo. However, it also pushed the nvm library onto there (hundreds of files). Now in my Github repo, there is a folder called "/home/ec2-user/.nvm" which I want to delete.

However, if I go into my git repo to delete it, it says:

`ec2-user:~/rails_projects/alpha-blog (master) $ git rm -r /home/ec2-user/.nvm
fatal: /home/ec2-user/.nvm: '/home/ec2-user/.nvm' is outside repository`

if I just do `rm -rf "/home/ec2-user/.nvm` nothing really happens.

Any idea what happened and how I can delete it from my Github repo?

Comment: The Git message is telling you that this folder is outside the repository, and so isn't managed by Git.  If this folder _is_ inside the Git repository on the remote repo, then it implies that the local and remote branches differ, and the folder in question perhaps has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is inside your repo, the command should be

```
ec2-user:~/rails_projects/alpha-blog (master) $ git rm -r home/ec2-user/.nvm
```

Meaning: the path should be relative from the root folder of your repo.

> Now in my Github repo, there is a folder called "/home/ec2-user/.nvm

You should see a subfolder `home` (with a sub-subfolder ec2-user, etc) under the root of your GitHub repo.

Comment: `ec2-user:~/rails_projects/alpha-blog (master) $ git rm -r home/ec2-user/.nvm` is what I used. And indeed in the Github root there is a home and ec2-user subfolder. However, from the terminal while inside the repo and trying to delete it, it gives the error that it's outside the repo.

Comment: @PhilipMan Can you try and clone that GitHub repo again (elsewhere)? And try again the rm? Can you check if you have any environment variable GIT_xxx in your current shell session? Do you have a `.gitmodules` file at the root of your repo?